# Error when trying to plot an animated graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, animated-gif

I have a data set in excel with 3 columns: `Date`, `Index` and `MetroArea`. I am trying to do an animated plot and this is the code I wrote. The error I get bakc says:

> Error in seq.default(range[1], range[2], length.out = nframes) : 
>     'from' must be a finite number

In addition: Warning messages:

> 1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf"

```
ggplot(housing_data, 
       aes(x=MetroArea, y=Index, label = MetroArea, color = MetroArea)) +
  geom_point(stat = 'identity', size = 10) +
  geom_segment(aes(y=100, x=MetroArea, yend=Index, xend=MetroArea)) +
  geom_text(color="black", size=3) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Date: {frame_time}", x='Date', y ='Index') +
  transition_time(date) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

Can someone please help me make progress?

Thank you!

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Hi @massisenergy. When you have a moment, would you mind taking a look at my related question here? Thanks! »»» https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030888/gganimate-ggplot2-error-when-using-transition-time-after-transforming-dataset